# gcc Stringification of expression with "%" sign

Tags: c, gcc, preprocessor, stringification

I`m trying to compile the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define __stringify_1(x...) #x
#define __stringify(x...)   __stringify_1(x)

#define FOO(expression)\
printf("prefix" __stringify(expression))

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   FOO(10 % 4); // <-- This is a problematic one 
   FOO(10 == 4); 
}
```

This yeilds a warning on compilation:
warning: conversion lacks type at end of format [-Wformat=]

The reason for this warning is that expression is actually expaneded to 
printf("prefix" "10 % 4"), hence compiler expects a "formatter". Is there any solution to pass such expressions to macro without getting a warning ?

Thanks

Comment: Use `puts` if you don't want formatting.

Comment: use `%%` to for `%`

Comment: @mat Or fputs() in case a newline character is not desired at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Use `printf("prefix%s", __stringify(expression))` to disable the formatting impact of `expression`.

Answer (score 1):

From [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/):

> A % followed by another % character will write a single % to the stream.

So, try double `%%`, like this:

```
FOO(10 %% 4);
```